# C++ other thread timer

Tags: c++

I have something like a timer in new thread

```
// creating thread
HANDLE thWriteUDP_500ms = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthreadex(
        NULL, 8096, Send_500ms, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL));
SetThreadPriority(thWriteUDP_500ms, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
ResumeThread(thWriteUDP_500ms);

// timer
unsigned int _stdcall Send_500ms(void*) {
    while (1) {
        // do stuff..
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Is it better way to do this, because "//do stuff.." sometimes takes up to 100ms, so iteration of timer takes longer, i need that if "do stuff.." take 100ms. Sleep() will be 500-100 (Sleep(400))

Comment: `using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock; auto waitEnd = Clock::now() + 500ms; /* do stuff */ std::this_thread::sleep_until(waitEnd);`???

Comment: What about perfomance? Is it good on same timer but with 50ms sleep? im talking about  Clock::now()

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_until` might be handy here.